# How to reset index without a following full crawl

Tags: sharepoint-server, index-reset

I would like to reduce our SharePoint Test environment disk size. Since we are not using the search feature on this test environment, I would like to purge all the index files to save space. I understand that by doing a index reset, SharePoint is able to clear all the index files. However, if I'm not mistaken, there will be a full crawl automatically kicks in after the index reset. Then the disk size will increase again.

My question is how to stop this following full crawl from kicking in. I'm thinking perhaps stopping the search service but I don't want to stop it if it is already running immediately after the index reset is done. Is there a gap between the completion of the index reset to the following full crawl? If there is, Is this gap based on time (next scheduled search service to be run) or a manual trigger (someone who used the search function for the first time after the index reset)? I just would like to find the right opportunity to stop the crawl without halting it while it's running or about to run. If that makes sense.

Environment: SharePoint 2013 On Prem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't auto trigger a full crawl, it just requires a full crawl to be run for the next crawl.  Easy way to be sure is to delete the content source before resetting the index, or just disable the crawl on the content source.  Also, resetting the index probably won't save much disk space unless you have a very large index.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to remove the content source first.

Comment: Just to append some info - Actually the default content source cannot be deleted. I ended up just left the search service suspended after the index reset.

Comment: You could always disable the crawl schedule, this no crawl of any type will run.